# Using the ccwc() function for risk set sampling WITHOUT replacement

Tags: r, replace, sampling

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the ccwc() function from the Epi package (risk set sampling) without replacement? If so, how is this specified? I have not been able to find anything about this in the documentation. See reproducible example below for how the function works:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(Epi)
library(survival)

### Create data frame:
Person_IDs <- seq(1,10000,1)
Example_DF <- as.data.frame(Person_IDs)
Example_DF$Start_Date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
Example_DF$Exposure_Date <- as.Date("2020-01-01") + days(sample (c(45:365), size=10000, replace =T))
Example_DF$End_Date <- as.Date("2021-05-01")
Example_DF$Sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size = 10000, replace = T)
Example_DF$Age <- sample(c(1:100), size = 10000, replace = T)
Example_DF$Fail <- sample(c(0,1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))

### Show first rows of data frame:
head(Example_DF)

## Set seed for the random number generator
set.seed(20140111)
## Generate a nested case-control study
Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement <- ccwc(entry    = Start_Date,    # Time of entry to follow-up
               exit     = Exposure_Date,    # Time of exit from follow-up
               fail     = Fail,    # Status on exit (1 = Fail, 0 = Censored)
               origin   = Start_Date,    # Origin of analysis time scale
               controls = 5,      # The number of controls to be selected for each case
               data     = Example_DF,   # data frame
               include = Person_IDs,
               match    = list(Age, Sex),    # List of categorical variables on which to match cases and controls
               silent   = TRUE
)
## Show how many times each person_ID is included as case and controls, respectively:
Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement[Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement$Fail == 1,] %>% group_by(Person_IDs) %>% tally(sort = TRUE)
## Only one for each person, which is supposed to be the case (can not be selected as case >1 time)

Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement[Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement$Fail == 0,] %>% group_by(Person_IDs) %>% tally(sort = TRUE)
## Many person IDs selected more than once, which is supposed to be the case if sampling with replacement is desired. I do however want sampling without replacement.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "without replacement". When I run `sum(duplicated(dietcc))` on your example I get 0. What is being duplicated?

Comment: Great comment IRTFM, I have now updated the reproducible example to a larger dataset to show that replacement does happen for the controls (as it is supposed to in many study designs).

Comment: I don't know. I'm puzzled because running `duplicated(Risk_Set_Sampling_With_Replacement)` still gets me 0. I do see that ID's are duplicated and I don't understand why that happens even after looking at the code of the function. I only see one call to `sample.int` and it is made without setting `replace="TRUE"` so I'm giving up.You might want to ask the maintainer if this doesn't attract a more informed response.